# Intra-observation dependence test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, independence

I have an observation matrix of size $200 \times 50$ where $200$ is the number of observations and $50$ is the number of variables.

I think the data has some kind of intra-observation dependence. For a given observation (e.g. the first row in the observation matrix), I think the value of the first variable predicts the values of the $49$ other variables. I think this is more or less the same for all participants.

In the end, I would like to examine correlations between few of the variables. Does the intra-observation dependence cause any problems?

How could I test the intra-observation dependence? Is there a better name for it?